# C++ Weird Behaviors With Multi-Threading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm processing video frame data via HLSL Pixel Shaders with DirectX 9. I want to run all operations in a row via a command buffer. Once the basic version is working (running commands one by one), then the execution of the following command will return the result of the previously generated frame, as there is a 1-frame delay with DirectX9 so that the GPU works on the previous frame while we're filling in the current frame data.

If I run 4 shaders with a single thread, I cannot get the frame for the next shader in the chain until I get the result of the first one, so the only way to get the correct output is to ask DX9 to render a dummy scene which cuts performance by half. When running on 8 threads, however, I should be able to have a command buffer that contains up to 8 commands and these can be chained one after the other. Right now I'm still processing them one by one (not chaining output yet), and it's not working the way I want.

There are all kinds of weird multi-threading issues.

I'm running 4 shaders on 8 threads, which results in 32 classes calling AddCommandToChain.

First, performance is VERY slow. If ProcessFrames is initiated for each class instance, then performance is MUCH higher; but then I end up having 32 DirectX devices which take up a lot of memory. In theory, the final version should provide twice better performance than when running with 32 devices.

Second, StartWorkerThread is sometimes called twice. There seems to be a race condition I haven't been able to solve.

Third, sometimes the code works fine, sometimes it deadlocks, sometimes if freezes for a while, randomly.

Fourth, I added a bunch of mutex locks and it works this way, but if I remove some of those locks, then I start getting all kinds of weird behaviors.

How can I "fix" this code to make it work in an acceptable way?

```
#include <list>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <concurrent_queue.h>
using namespace concurrency;

static int threadCount;
static concurrent_queue<CommandStruct> cmdBuffer;
static std::mutex initLock, startLock, waiterLock;
static std::thread* WorkerThread;
static HANDLE WorkerWaiting;
static void AddCommandToQueue(CommandStruct* cmd, IScriptEnvironment* env);
static void StartWorkerThread(IScriptEnvironment* env);## Heading ##

int Shader::threadCount = 0;
concurrent_queue<CommandStruct> Shader::cmdBuffer;
std::mutex Shader::startLock, Shader::initLock, Shader::waiterLock;
std::once_flag OnceFlag;
std::thread* Shader::WorkerThread = NULL;
HANDLE Shader::WorkerWaiting = NULL;

void Shader::AddCommandToQueue(CommandStruct* cmd, IScriptEnvironment* env) {
    // Add command to queue.
    cmdBuffer.push(*cmd);

    // If thread is idle or not running, make it run.
    if (WorkerWaiting != NULL)
        SetEvent(WorkerWaiting);
    if (WorkerThread == NULL) {
        startLock.lock();
        if (WorkerThread == NULL)
            WorkerThread = new std::thread(StartWorkerThread, env);
        startLock.unlock();
    }
}

void Shader::StartWorkerThread(IScriptEnvironment* env) {
    if (WorkerThread != NULL)
        return;

    ProcessFrames Worker(env);

    // Start waiting event with a state meaning it's not waiting.
    WorkerWaiting = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL);

    // Process all commands in the queue.
    CommandStruct CurrentCmd, PreviousCmd;
    if (!cmdBuffer.try_pop(CurrentCmd))
        CurrentCmd.Path = NULL;
    while (CurrentCmd.Path != NULL) {
        // The result of the 1st execution will be returned on the 2nd call.
        if (FAILED(Worker.Execute(&CurrentCmd, NULL)))
            env->ThrowError("Shader: Failed to execute command");
        initLock.lock();
        SetEvent(CurrentCmd.Event); // Notify that processing is completed.
        initLock.unlock();

        PreviousCmd = CurrentCmd;
        if (!cmdBuffer.try_pop(CurrentCmd))
            CurrentCmd.Path = NULL;

        while (CurrentCmd.Path != NULL) {
            if (FAILED(Worker.Execute(&CurrentCmd, NULL)))
                env->ThrowError("Shader: Failed to execute command");
            initLock.lock();
            SetEvent(CurrentCmd.Event); // Notify that processing is completed.
            initLock.unlock();
            PreviousCmd = CurrentCmd;
            if (!cmdBuffer.try_pop(CurrentCmd))
                CurrentCmd.Path = NULL;
        }

        // Flush the device to get last frame.
        //Worker.Flush(&PreviousCmd);
        //SetEvent(PreviousCmd.WorkerEvent); // Notify that processing is completed.

        // When queue is empty, Wait for event to be set by AddCommandToQueue.
        waiterLock.lock();
        WaitForSingleObject(WorkerWaiting, 10000);
        ResetEvent(WorkerWaiting);

        // If there are still no commands after timeout, stop thread.
        if (!cmdBuffer.try_pop(CurrentCmd))
            CurrentCmd.Path = NULL;
        waiterLock.unlock();
    }

    // Release event and thread.
    startLock.lock();
    CloseHandle(WorkerWaiting);
    WorkerWaiting = NULL;
    WorkerThread = NULL;
    startLock.unlock();
}
```

EDIT: Even though I'm clearly adding the command to the buffer before calling SetEvent(WorkerWaiting), within the thread, WaitForSingleObject(WorkerWaiting, 10000) gets released while the buffer is still empty!? And the thread exits repeatedly.

Here's the full code file on Github
https://github.com/mysteryx93/AviSynthShader/blob/master/Src/WorkerThread.h

Comment: Use `std::lock_guard` instead of calling `lock()` `unlock()` manually.

Comment: It's not changing anything. In fact, that change made it even more unstable. In terms of performance, this code (when it works) runs at 16fps, while when I initiate 32 devices, it runs at 39fps, and then I remove the 2nd dummy scene (which corrupts the output), it runs at 78fps.

Comment: Third parameter in CreateEvent describes initial state. You create it already signaled and WaitForSingleObject doesn't wait for anything.